# eclipse not starting in windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8, adt

I have downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717.zip and extracted it in my windows 8 pc. I have java version "1.7.0_25" installed and the path variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin; Whenever I click the eclipse application that was bundled with the download, it doesnt launch. The message that windows shows is attached here. How can I resolve this issue ?[image]

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 7?

Comment: @Simon You mean downgrade ;-)

Comment: You've attempted to actually **USE** windows 8. That's not supported. We're just supposed to bask in the glory of the tiles and gossip about how metro it all is.

Comment: @JunedAhsan, nope, I meant upgrade ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have JAVA_HOME and JRE environments set. Also it helps to have x64-bit JRE installed, if you are on a 64-bit OS and have the 64-bit Eclipse installed.

Comment: How can I ensure if JAVA_HOME and JRE environments set? And I am on 64-bit OS and 32-bit Eclipse by the way

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud simply open a command prompt and type echo %JAVE_HOME%, if set it will print it. If not then you cn

Comment: Or just type `set` to see all vars.

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html.
It runs without much of a problem on my Windows 8 machine.
Also make sure you have JAVA_HOME as a system variable pointing to 64-bit JDK, Android Studio won't even install without it.

You have 64-bit OS, 64-bit JDK and 32-bit Eclipse that wasn't working for me, try with 64-bit Eclipse as Juned suggests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty nice video for installing Eclipse on windows 8
[on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1prmlgf9-JI).

Additionally here is a step by step

1. Make sure java works and is [installed properly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Ensure environment variables for java are set and|or [path has java added](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
   by going to the command line and typing java. From there you should get a prompt that starts with the following

   `Usage: java [-options] class [args...]`
3. Download [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr) or another IDE such as [Ideaj](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) or [NetBeans](https://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid)

   (if eclipse)[Install ADT Plugin](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) (else follow IDE docs for android install)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java 8 update.
It will work fine.

Comment: This is more of a commentary rather than an answer. You need to give an explanation to be able to give an answer